# Header in .txt file in talend

Tags: header, talend

Im new at Talend, and I want to generate an Interface file(.txt) . and, I have generated one. But, I have a problem. because I need to add the ff:
     RecordAmount=5
     Type=1
     User-ID=1234
at the top part of .txt file.

"","","","","",""
   "","","","","",""

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Please more clearly explain what output you are trying to achieve and what you're currently get (it might also help if you show us how you're getting the wrong output too).

Comment: Hi. I was able to create my .txt file. I just don't know how to add header (not the Column names) but sample is this, "RecordAmount=<count number of records> \n Type=1>..... which should be located on the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple of options here:

You can unite two different data flows (that must have the same schema but could artificially be so) to append your main data set on to your header data:

[image: Using a tUnite to add the header]

Here, I've set my data up using 2 tFixedFlowInput components for simplicity's sake. This could be any data flow/set though from any component or progressed from a more complicated job and the header could also be generated by a process run through the job.

For the tUnite component you need to match the schema so for here I have some example main data with a simple schema of id, name and age for demonstration:

[image: Main data for uniting]

We then set the header data to have the same schema:

[image: Header Unite Schema]

And fill it with the data that we want to appear at the top of the file:

[image: Header Unite data]

The tUnite then merges all of the inputs in order (notice how the merge order for the header link is the first and the remaining data is the second).

The other alternative is to output just the header row to a file, whether that's as a delimited file using the tFileOutputDelimited if you want the header row to have the option to be split across fields or just a flat single field row using the tFileOutputRaw component, and then append the remaining data to it using the "Append" option in the tFileOutputDelimited.

As an example job we might do something like this:

[image: Appending data to a header]

In this case we have a similar data set for both but a slight tweak on the data to show that not all columns would need to be filled and the schemas no longer have to be the same:

[image: Header data for append job][image: Data to append to header]

And then all we do to make sure that the data is properly appended is to set our tFileOutputDelimited components up like so:

[image: Append header output configuration in tFileOutputDelimited][image: Append data output configuration in tFileOutputDelimited]

Pay close attention to the fact that the "Append" option is ticked in the output for the main data.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tFileOutputFullRow with a tRowGenerator to create your first row.
Next step is to turn on the Append mode of the DelimitedOutput, and you're done.

Comment: Hi. I don't see tFileOutputFullRow on my Talend